# What gem should I use for authentication with rails 4.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently building a web app that will two levels of access; open and admin. I have tried using devise with cancan, but it turns out that the current stable release of devise has issues with rails 4.2. Can I get a suggestion on what other gems might work great. I have researched a couple, but I wanted a suggestion based on other people's experiences.

Answer (score 1):

Devise is based on Warden, so you could try using Warden for your web app.

https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki

Warden's definitely a bit more barebones than Devise but it helps to learn how Devise works and appreciate Devise's added functions.

Plus, what issues are you speaking of with the current release of Devise? I'm currently using it with my web app and don't really see any problems.